# Sending class data as JSON array format for GET request Response in ASP.Net Dot Core Web API ( GET response data from Web API)

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I am writing a Web API with requirement where need to pass result class property values as array of Json in response of GET request.
Property class which will be passed as a actual result with Ok Status with object. ( I am mocking actual requirement)

```
public class ABC
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Address{get;set;}
}
```

I am following default JSONfor matter option which are available in dotnet core web api and it is converting all class attribute into single json element.

```
{
  "Person" : 
             [
             {
              "Name": "ABCD",
              "Address": "INDIA"
              }
             ]
}
```

My requirement is to have data in Json format with array as below -

```
{
  "Person" : 
             [
              {"Name": "ABCD"},
              {"Address": "INDIA"}
             ]
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**=== Updated my answer to reflect clarified details ===**

### **Solution with Json.Net:**

To get the JSON result that you're looking for, you'll need to create a custom serializer or build your JSON object with dynamic JTokens.

Here's an example using a dynamic JObject:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/EyL5Um

Code:

```
// Create sample object to serialize
var person = new ABC() { Name = "ABC",  Address = "India" };
        
// Build JSON with dynamic JTokens
dynamic jsonObj = new JObject();
        
var token = new JArray();

token.Add(new JObject(
     new JProperty("Name", person.Name)));

token.Add(new JObject(
     new JProperty("Address", person.Address)));

jsonObj.Person = token;
        
// Print result to console
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.ToString());
```

### Note

In this form, the code above is not a scalable solution. But it should provide you with a starting point to then build up an iterative approach for the data you're working with.

### **References**

[Newtonsoft Documentation - Create JSON w/ Dynamic](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonDynamic.htm)

Comment: Corrected My question , I have to send back response as JSON array. And I tried using list and adding a class to it. Unfortunately it behaves in same way as I described for my question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help ! Still it is not having name in separate element and Address in a separate ( I mean separate curly braces { } ) .

Answer (score 1):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

use this method to convert obj to string:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)
```

use this method to convert string to obj:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)
```